# Select the nearest value before and after

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

let say the table is show_date

```
different | date
----------------------  
    -2    | 2011-04-18
----------------------
    -1    | 2011-04-19
----------------------
     4    | 2011-04-24
----------------------
     5    | 2011-04-25 
----------------------
```

I want to select 2 values, the first one is the first negative value and the second one is the first positive value.
in this sample will result -1 (2011-04-19) and 4 (2011-04-24)

I've try order by abs(different) but it give the 2 nearest which is -1 and -2

Comment: Could you be clearer on inputs? You have this table and you input `<what>` to get the nearest positive and negative value of `<what>`? Is it that you input a date and find the nearest dates before and after that date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  MIN(CASE WHEN different > 0 THEN different ELSE NULL END) AS MinPositive,
  MAX(CASE WHEN different < 0 THEN different ELSE NULL END) AS MaxNegative
FROM show_date
```

Comment: @Yanuar Lutfi: this doesn't return `date`

Answer (score 4):

```
(SELECT * FROM show_date WHERE different < 0 ORDER BY different DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM show_date WHERE different >= 0 ORDER BY different LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: @Yanuar Lutfi: 1. it is a single query. 2. what's wrong with `UNION`? 3. Why the hell you didn't mention that in Q before I waste my time???

Comment: @yanuar-lutfi Any particular reason why?

Comment: @Yanuar You may want to use union but it is the only way you can get the desired result.  Thank the man for his time and accept his answer.

Comment: the table is a summary of select * from (select * from some_table), if possible I don't want another select over select

Comment: Here is a "single query" *although it will perform worse*: `SELECT *
FROM show_date s
 JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(ABS(different)) different
  FROM show_date
  GROUP BY different < 0
 ) g USING(different)`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   min (a.nr), 
   max (b.nr) 
FROM 
  demo a, 
  demo b 
WHERE a.nr > 0 
  AND b.nr < 0;

 min | max
-----+----
   1 | -1
(1 Row)
```

An alternative approach - above solution gets problematic for large tables:

```
SELECT min(date)
  FROM tbl 
  WHERE date > 0
UNION 
SELECT max(date) 
  FROM tbl 
  WHERE date < 0;
```

Comment: Even though I upvoted this - I still don't think that Cartesian product is appropriate for this task.

Comment: Depends on the size of your table, and the cleverness of the analyzer, doesn't it?

Comment: @user unknown: I wouldn't say that mysql's optimizer is clever ;-) If we were talking about oracle 10+, then probably yes, but not mysql's.

Comment: @zerkms: Why, MySQL hasn't reached version 10 yet, so no wonder. :)

Comment: @Andriy M: don't forget that mysql also hasn't reached oracle's dbms price yet ;-)

Comment: mysql or not - many tables contain just a few rows. There the solution is appropriate.